# NumPY floor or ceiling based on row number

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like so:

```
>>> arr
array([[1, 2,  2.5],
       [3, 4, 3.75],
       [5, 6, 1.25],
       [7, 8,  1.3],
       [9, 0,  3.5]])
```

I wish to perform a `math.floor` or `math.ceil` operation on the 3rd column **based on row number**. So if the row number is odd, perform a `ceil` operation, if row number is even, perform a `floor` operation. Like so:

```
>>> func(arr)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 3],
       [5, 6, 2],
       [7, 8, 1],
       [9, 0, 4]])
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With slicing -

```
arr[::2,2] = np.ceil(arr[::2,2])
arr[1::2,2] = np.floor(arr[1::2,2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where`, and also, `np.floor`, instead of `math.floor`, allows you to operate on numpy arrays.

```
mask = np.arange(len(arr))%2

arr[:,-1] = np.where(mask, np.floor(arr[:,-1]), np.ceil(arr[:,-1]))

# if you want to apply to all array, use
# np.where(mask[:,None], np.floor(arr), np.ceil(arr))
```

Output:

```
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [3., 4., 3.],
       [5., 6., 2.],
       [7., 8., 1.],
       [9., 0., 4.]])
```